# validates length of problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My problem is: the code below works fine but there is one special case. If item's product_id is 1 then item can have up to 10 keywords. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

validates_length_of :keywords, :maximum => 5,  :tokenizer => lambda {|str| str.scan(/\w+/) }, :on => :update 

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validates_length_of :keywords, :maximum => 5,  :tokenizer => lambda {|str| str.scan(/\w+/) }, :on => :update, :unless => lambda { |item| item.product_id == 1 }
```

Comment: You would also probably want a second validation with a maximum of 10, and change the `:unless` to an `:if`.